# how to use python to authenticate using okta and perform an action

Tags: python, okta

I have a web portal, it uses okta for user authentication.

I need to write a python script and perform a post operation on the portal app.

I tried using requests python library

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

import requests

s= requests.session()

login_data = {'username':'XXXXXX', 'password': 'XXXXXXXX'}
r = s.post('https://example.okta.com/login/login.htm', login_data)

#print(r.cookies)
data = {"type": "live"}
r2 = s.post('https://example.com/merchant', data=data)
```

This doesn't seem to work, I not getting a session created and not seeing the post happening on the portal

Comment: If you're using Flask, this tutorial might help: https://developer.okta.com/blog/2018/07/12/flask-tutorial-simple-user-registration-and-login

Comment: In your 2nd request the `r` variable should be included as an auth key I think. Somehow. Try to look it up.